# sperate row show data in single csv

Tags: magento2

i am getting product from order collection last 7 days and generation csv as report as you can see in my code now i am getting same sku operate but i want if same sku twice then its show 1 time with add qty and price total how i can achieve this?

Means sku ABC order 2 different customers then its show only with qty e.g 2

```
 public function execute()
    {
     
        $filepath = 'export/customerlist.csv';
        $this->directory->create('export');

       

        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $header = ['Sku', 'Name', 'Price','Qty','Date'];
        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        $data = [];
        $newarray = [];
        
        $qty=1; 
        $orders = $this->getOrderCollectionByDateRange();
        

       foreach ($orders as $order) {
       
          foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {



           
                if(in_array($item->getSku(), $newarray)) {

                    $qty += $item->getQtyOrdered();
                    
                } else {

                    
                    $data['sku'] = $item->getSku();
                    $data['name'] = $item->getName();
                    $data['price'] = $item->getPrice();
                    $data['qty'] = $qty;
                    $data['created_at'] = $order->getCreatedAt();
                    $stream->writeCsv($data);
        
                }
               

                array_push($newarray, $item->getSku());
               
                
            
        }
        
    }
   

    }
```

like in see here it show 2 product with same sku spreatly i want in same row like qty 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your object can get all visible items from the order simply using $order->getAllVisibleItems() which will give you all visible items of an order. But that return with an array of all items that are not marked as deleted and do not have a parent item.

What you can do is use:

**getItems()**: returns array of items from loaded order item collection.

**getAllItems()**: returns an array of all items that are not marked as deleted.

**getAllVisibleItems()**: returns an array of all items that are not marked as deleted and do not have a parent item.

Note that, as of Magento-2.0 only getItems() is part of the service contract in Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface.

Or you put a filter in if condition to check if the SKU is appear again:

```
// to check if the item is deleted
if (!$item->isDeleted()) {
     $items[] = $item;
 }

// To check SKU exists
$newarray = []
if (in_array($item->getSku(), $newarray)) {
   // do nothing
else {
   // load data into it
} 
array_push($newarray, $item->getSku())
```

Comment: what about qty how i hand qty i need to add qty

Comment: Just add the quantity then like:
$qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();

if (in_array($item->getSku(), $newarray)) {
   $qty += $item->getQtyOrdered();
}
else {
   $data[] = $qty
}

Comment: how passed in csv i am using data[]

Comment: It already informed in my above code in else condition:
$data[] = $qty

Comment: i tried but not working qty no increase

Comment: Could you please type your whole code script here?

Comment: code updated in description

Comment: i tried as you mentioned let me know

Comment: if i do this then same sku item start show agian

Comment: Please check the updated code in next answer

Comment: i check but if same sku its rpeated row if abc sku 2 time its showing sku abc qty1 and sku abc qty2

Comment: Array
(
    [sku] => 124499
    [name] => abc
    [price] => 35.03
    [qty] => 1.0000
    [created_at] => 2022-09-23 07:57:17
)
Array
(
    [sku] => 124499
    [name] => abc
    [price] => 35.03
    [qty] => 2
    [created_at] => 2022-09-23 08:59:13
)
Array
(
    [sku] => 132752
    [name] => cdef
    [price] => 40.88
    [qty] => 1.0000
    [created_at] => 2022-09-23 08:59:13
)

Comment: Did you try the below updated answer code?

Comment: yes i tried   ...

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: nooooooo........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139813/discussion-between-jyotishina-rajwani-and-imt).

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the code like this:

```
        if(in_array($item->getSku(), $newarray)) {
            $qty += $item->getQtyOrdered();    
        } else {
            $qty =  $item->getQtyOrdered();      
        }
            
            $data['sku'] = $item->getSku();
            $data['name'] = $item->getName();
            $data['price'] = $item->getPrice();
            $data['qty'] = $qty;
            $data['created_at'] = $order->getCreatedAt();
            $stream->writeCsv($data);
```